# Trouble figuring out syntax for pointer casting

Tags: c, nrf52

I was working today when I came across the following function:

```
void button_scheduler_event_handler(void *p_event_data, uint16_t event_size)
{
    button_handler(*((nrf_drv_gpiote_pin_t*)p_event_data));
}
```

with button handler defined as the following:

```
void button_handler(nrf_drv_gpiote_pin_t pin)
```

I'm not sure Í have encountered this syntax:

```
button_handler(*((nrf_drv_gpiote_pin_t*)p_event_data));
```

before and I am a bit bewildered. My first thought is that the syntax for calling button_handler should be:

```
button_handler(((*nrf_drv_gpiote_pin_t) *p_event_data));
```

I do however not have any good explanation for why.

Can anyone explain this?

Edit: after input from user UnholySheep

Comment: `*((nrf_drv_gpiote_pin_t*)p_event_data)` is a (pointer) cast followed by a dereferencing. This has nothing to do with function pointers

Comment: Since `nrf_drv_gpiote_pin_t` is a type, `nrf_drv_gpiote_pin_t*` is also a type, and `*nrf_drv_gpiote_pin_t` is nonsense.

Comment: With `void *p_event_data`, `*p_event_data` is   invalid: attempt to de-reference a `void *`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `p_event_data` parameter is declared as a `void *`, meaning it could point to anything.  However, based on the fact that it calls `button_handler`, it suggests that `p_event_data` is actually pointing to a `nrf_drv_gpiote_pin_t`.

So first you need to cast the `void *` to a `nrf_drv_gpiote_pin_t *`:

```
(nrf_drv_gpiote_pin_t  *)p_event_data
```

Then you need to dereference that pointer:

```
*((nrf_drv_gpiote_pin_t  *)p_event_data)
```

And that's what gets passed to `button_handler`.

Comment: I got to the same conclusion after UnholySheep pointed me in the right direction! - Never the less thanks for taking the time to answer!